# Expo - Is it possible to verify a user email on signup from firebase? (the link that firebase sends to an email doesn't redirect back to my app)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am using Expo Go currently in development and can't find a solution to this anywhere...

I’m trying to use `firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, { url: // I don't know what url to put here to redirect user back to my app })` || I want to send a verification email to a new user but I can’t find anyway to redirect the user back to my Expo Go app from the email link that is sent. I can’t use exp:// or another scheme because I have to use a domain name that I can put in google's authorized domains within firebase. I have also tried auth.expo.io/@myusername/myproject but this only redirects correctly back to my app when using Expo's AuthSession for logging users directly into my app with credentials.

Please someone send some light on this!